# My PHP login page is not working properly

Tags: php, html

I was looking for PHP tutorials for login pages. I have done the same files but when I press login, it shows me a blank page.
I have opened PHPMyAdmin page and added a database called `admin_logs` with a table of `users`.

#### login.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Teacher Login</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="logstyle.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="header">
            <h2>Login</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="input-group">
            <form method="POST" action="functions.php">
                <label>Username</label>
                <input type="text" id="username" name="username" >
                <label>Password</label>
                <input type="password" id="password" name="password">
                <button type="submit" class="btn" name="login_btn">Login</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

#### functions.php

```
<?php

    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    $username = stripcslashes($username);
    $password = stripcslashes($password);
    $username = mysql_real_escape_string($username);
    $password = mysql_real_escape_string($password);

    mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
mysql_select_db("admin_logs");

    $result = mysql_query("select * from users where username = '$username' and password = '$password'")
            or die("Failed to query database".mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
if ($row['username'] == $username && $row['password'] == $password){
    echo "Login success. Welcome".$row['username']; 
} else {
    echo "Failed to login.";
}
?>
```

Comment: Is there any error in error.log file?? Can you var_dump($row) and tell me what you see there?

Comment: why are you sure that the user always exists? `$row` may be false if the user is not found.

Comment: @KaushikC sorry i'm a beginner to php i just needed this page, how do i do that var_dump() ?

Comment: @RustamD9RS i just found the source code online but didn't work for a reason i dont really understand because php is not my expertise

Comment: Please put `var_dump($row); die();` after `$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);` this line

and please let me know what you see.

Comment: @KaushikC i did what you asked,nothing happens

Comment: When you are clicking on submit button, the request should go to functions.php. Is the request going to functions.php? . Is the path correct in actions for function.php file ? If it is called, check database is connected. Debug every line one by one until where the code is running ? Its impossible to know the issue without any error. Also rename the login.php to login.html if it is pure html in it.

Comment: 1. Use PHP 7+ 2. DON'T use mysql_* 3. don't store plain passwords

Comment: Sadly there is a lot of really, **really** bad PHP "tutorials" hanging around on the internet. `:-(`

Answer (score 4):

There are many things to fix here.

- `mysql_*` functions are **removed** from PHP. You should use [PDO](https://www.php.net/pdo) instead. It can be a bit of a learning curve, but once you get the hang of it you will have a much easier time.
- You should *never* put user input in a query string - *even with `escape_string()`* as there could still potentially be implementation issues. For example, if you have a numeric field, you might not put quotes around the value, and this allows injection even with the "escaped" string. Use `prepare`d statements instead, and pass in the values separately. This will keep your database queries secure.
- Create a user/password for your MySQL database, and **don't use `root` for database operations**. In fact, put a password on your `root` user right away!!!
- **Don't store passwords as plain text!** This is a *serious* security flaw - to the point where websites that do this are [named and shamed](https://plaintextoffenders.com/). You should use [`password_hash`](https://php.net/password-hash) to secure the password on user registration, so that you *never* know what the user's password is. Then, use [`password_verify`](https://php.net/password-verify) on user login to authenticate them.
- Your logic could use some re-working. Currently you are looking up a user with the username and password given, and then checking if the username and password match. Clearly they do! What you should be doing instead - combined with the above - is check if the user exists and retrieve the (hashed!) password. Then verify if the password given matches the hash you have saved, and that's when you allow the user in.
- Once you have your login stuff working, you can use `$_SESSION` to store the user's logged-in status. This will allow you to just check - for example - `$_SESSION['userid']` to see if the user has logged in.

You really should look for some *up-to-date* tutorials on this stuff, as things have changed *significantly* in the last 7 years (that's how long `mysql_query` has been deprecated for!)

Answer (score -1):

First of all, you need to encrypt the password using  SHA-256 or SHA-1, and I don't recommend MD5!

You don't need to change the user and password against the post method. Try using:

```
 if (mysql_num_rows($row)) {  
   echo "Login success.   Welcome".$row['username']; 
 } else {
   echo "Failed to login.";
 }
```

Don't forget to set the session once the user is authenticated!

Comment: **Warning:** `mysql_*` extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and has been removed as of PHP 7.0.0. Instead, either the [mysqli](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO_MySQL](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) extension should be used. See also the [MySQL API Overview](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) for further help while choosing a MySQL API.

Answer (score -1):

Try to adding these lines just after the PHP opening tag in functions.php

```
> ini_set('display_errors', '1'); 
> ini_set('display_startup_errors','1');
> error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Post back the output.

Using your logic-> depracated and not in my opinion the best approach:

```
> $result = mysql_query("select * from users where username =
> '$username' and password = '$password'")
>             or die("Failed to query database".mysql_error());
>         if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
>              while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
>                  echo "Login success. Welcome".$row['username']; 
>                 
>             }
>         } else {
>             echo "Failed to login.";
>         }
```

Comment: found the problem,appareantly it was the double quotes... now it gives this error :
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_real_escape_string() in D:\xampp\htdocs\Online-Quiz\functions.php:7 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in D:\xampp\htdocs\Online-Quiz\functions.php on line 7

Comment: see @Niet the Dark Absol 's answer. The error you get now is being triggered because mysql_* functions are no longer in use in PHP 7

Comment: **Warning:** `mysql_*` extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and has been removed as of PHP 7.0.0. Instead, either the [mysqli](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO_MySQL](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) extension should be used. See also the [MySQL API Overview](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) for further help while choosing a MySQL API.